# jquery using parent or siblings

Tags: jquery

Hello i have multiple galleries on one page and also using a light-box script. Instead of having to id each gallery differently i think i can use parent or siblings function, but i cant get it working can anyone help?

```
<div id'gallery'>
<a id='galImage'>.....</a>
<a id='galImage'>.....</a>
<a id='galImage'>.....</a>
</div>

<div id'gallery'>
<a id='galImage'>.....</a>
<a id='galImage'>.....</a>
<a id='galImage'>.....</a>
</div>

<div id'gallery'>
<a id='galImage'>.....</a>
<a id='galImage'>.....</a>
<a id='galImage'>.....</a>
</div>
```

the script i'm using is

```
$(function() {
   $('#gallery #imageGal').lightBox({
    overlayBgColor: '#FFF',
   });
});
```

i've tried

```
$(function() {
   $("#gallery + #imageGal", this).lightBox({
    overlayBgColor: '#FFF',
   });
});
```

Comment: **IDs must be UNIQUE!**

Comment: You cant have multiple elements with the same id, it is invalid and can have unpredictable results. If you need them to be called the same, change the id's  to class.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use another attribute instead of ID for such purposes. For example:

```
<div gallery='true'>
  <a galImage='true'>.....</a>
  <a galImage='true'>.....</a>
  <a galImage='true'>.....</a>
</div>
```

And the script for update:

```
$(function() {
   $('div[gallery] a[imageGal]').lightBox({
    overlayBgColor: '#FFF',
   });
});
```

Comment: Don't use custom attributes. They are as invalid as duplicate IDs (from a specification point of view. `data-*` attributes are fine, but classes would suffice here).

Comment: I think that the `class` should be used as it is designed, not for selectors. As for the custom attributes, they are quite valid, just require additional declatations http://www.w3schools.com/DTD/dtd_attributes.asp

Comment: thanks but that combines all the galleries i need them defined by each <div> group

Comment: In XML yes, you can define your own attributes, but not in HTML. HTML already has a DTD, you cannot use your own or extend it. As for the `class` attribute, what do you think it was designed for? The [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-class) says: *"As a style sheet selector (when an author wishes to assign style information to a set of elements). / For **general purpose processing** by user agents."*

Comment: @gareth then use the selector `$('div[gallery]')` this will give you each `div` separately

Comment: @FelixKling I see, thanks. I (personally) prefer not to use class for _general purpose processing_ and never had problems with custom attributes, but when the man want to have his code to be compartible with specification, then you are right, my way is not the best one.